# Debian - software RAID 1 in UEFI mode

Tags: linux, debian, raid, uefi, gpt

I am a beginner in UEFI, so excuse me if this question is vey simple. I have two 3 TB disks and want to install Debian 9.4 with RAID1 in UEFI mode.After reading all the information I am thinking about such configuration:

```
sda1 512 MB EFI
sda2 5 GB RAID
sda3 rest RAID

sdb1 512 MB EFI
sdb2 5 GB RAID
sdb3 rest RAID

and I create two raid:
/md0 RAID 1 - swap              (sda2 and sdb2)
/md1 RAID 1 - ext4 mounted as / (sda3 and sdb3)
```

Will such configuration work without any problems in UEFI mode? Or it is wrong?

Comment: I would recommend that you make the ESPs at least 1Gb.